# Vertically aligning the first letter of each line in a \centering environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment

In a book project, I'm using `\centering` to place verses in the center of the page. As expected, the text is laid out such that each line of the verse is centered. I would like to retain the centering for line #1 while forcing the first character of the line #2 to be vertically aligned with the first character of the line #1 of the verse. My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newenvironment{myverse}
{\nopagebreak\centering}

\begin{document}
% Will replace period with unicode । and ॥ later
\begin{myverse}
dharmakṣetre kurukṣetre samavetā yuyutsavaḥ .\\ 
māmakāḥ pāṇḍavāścaiva kimakurvata sañjaya . 1-1.\\
\end{myverse}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput]

In the output, I would like the first letter of line #2 i.e `m` to be placed directly below `d` - the first letter of line #1.

Is this possible? If `\centering` is not the best environment, what can be done to get the desired layout?

Comment: I think you mean horizontal alignment not vertical, you could just use a verse enviornment, or if you want to centre on the longest line, use a a tabular.

Comment: you are also missing the end definition of your enviornment, just avoiding an error as the blank line is taken as the argument to `\newenvironment`

Comment: I wasn't aware of this error at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *horizontal* alignment, not vertical.

You want to left align the text block while centering the block as a whole, so here I use an `l` column in a centred tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newenvironment{myverse}
{\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{l}}
{\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
% Will replace period with unicode । and ॥ later
\begin{myverse}
dharmakṣetre kurukṣetre samavetā yuyutsavaḥ .\\ 
māmakāḥ pāṇḍavāścaiva kimakurvata sañjaya . 1-1.\\
\end{myverse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick solution!

Answer (score 2):

Try the `verse` package which lets you control many aspects of typesetting verses. Here is a revision of your MWE, for which thank you.

```
% verseprob.tex  SE 577265
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\mylength}  % just as a convenience

\newenvironment{myverse}
{\nopagebreak\centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
% Will replace period with unicode । and ॥ later
\begin{myverse}
dharmakṣetre kurukṣetre samavetā yuyutsavaḥ .\\ 
māmakāḥ pāṇḍavāścaiva kimakurvata sañjaya . 1-1.\\
\end{myverse}
\end{comment}

\lipsum[1]

% the length of a typical line
\settowidth{\mylength}{dharmakṣetre kurukṣetre samavetā yuyutsavaḥ .}

\begin{verse}[\mylength]
dharmakṣetre kurukṣetre samavetā yuyutsavaḥ .\\ 
māmakāḥ pāṇḍavāścaiva kimakurvata sañjaya . 1-1.\\
\end{verse}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

With the verse package providing the optional length argument to `\begin{verse}[<length>]`, where `<length>` is the average length of the verse lines, then the verse lines will be typeset with the mid point of `<length>` centered in the page.

[image]

Comment: Super! thanks for the pointer to the verse package.